# D2D Sharpen Effect

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, direct2d

I have to write Windows 8.1 application which use sharpen effect for image processing with Direct2D

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn900461%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) built-in effect could resolve my problem, but i'm not able to include d2d1effects_2.h, because this header is missing.Both **d2d1.lib** and **dxguid.lib** are linked to project. This header even seems to be missed on drive.

[image]

Does anybody knows where the problem might be?

Comment: Most probably, `d2d1effects_2.h` is a part of the new Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: But MSDN says that minimum supported client is Windows 8.1.

Comment: Minimum supported client means that the client has the needed binaries (ie - the proper d2d1.lib/dll version). Anyway, you need a specific header, which is not a part from the Windows 8 SDK for sure.

Comment: Peter is correct.  I have used the sharpen effect for Win81, and I have not yet coded anything for Win10.  d2d1effects_1.h is included with the Win81 kit (same path except for '8.1' in place of '10', however there isn't much in it.

Answer (score 0):

`d2d1effects_2.h` is a part from the Windows 10 SDK.

You can obtain it by downloading the latest SDK for Windows 8.1 from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx).

After, install it and check here - `%programfiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10069.0\um\`